# In Algorithm Complexity - What is a DegenerateProblem instance?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

To my knowledge, a problem instance is an example of an algorithm using real numbers.

I see the term "Degenerate Problem Instance" thrown around a lot in Comp Sci text books. What does it mean?

Comment: It's problem- and sometimes even algorithm-specific, though the common thread is a problematic set of inputs having measure zero. Did you have a question about a particular usage?

Comment: Hey @DavidEisenstat, my question is regarding the Knapsack Problem

Comment: That's an unusual context. Could you go into more detail about what was said?

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be easier to answer correctly if you gave examples and references of the use of this term. However, I suspect from web-searching the term that it refers to cases where by unlucky chance the input is in some very special arrangement which leads e.g. to parallel lines or multiple points in the same place or something and this leads code which assumes that bad things never happen to fail over, typically by dividing by zero. See e.g. https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/DegeneracyGeometry.pdf